# Hibernate 6 Upgrade - H2 Query Syntax Issue

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to upgrade an existing app from Spring Boot 2.7/Hibernate 5.4 to Spring Boot 3.1.2/Hibernate 6.2.6. Both setups use H2 2.1.214.

Tests that used to work in the original setup are failing. I've debugged this to a point that I know it is because of the way a JPQL query is getting translated in SQL. In the working version, the query gets translated as below.

> update account_balances set balance_magnitude=balance_magnitude+?,
> unreconciled_debit_amount_magnitude=unreconciled_debit_amount_magnitude+?,
> unreconciled_credit_amount_magnitude=unreconciled_credit_amount_magnitude+?
> where account_id=?

Whereas, with the new combination, the query gets translated as below.

> update account_balances set
> balance_magnitude=(balance_magnitude+cast(? as
> numeric($p,$s))),unreconciled_debit_amount_magnitude=(unreconciled_debit_amount_magnitude+cast(?
> as
> numeric($p,$s))),unreconciled_credit_amount_magnitude=(unreconciled_credit_amount_magnitude+cast(?
> as numeric($p,$s))) where account_id=?

And the error thrown is as below.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement
> ***  **expected "long"**;

The *_magnitude columns have type `DECIMAL(14,2)` in DB and `BigDecimal` in Java. The dialect used is **H2Dialect**.

The jdbc url is as given below
**jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;NON_KEYWORDS=year;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1**

What could be the reason?

Thanks.